# How to compare different forecasting models (TS, ML, DL) using the same and replicable validation method

Tags: python, forecasting, cross-validation, validation

I am working on a research problem in which I compare an ARIMA, a lightGBM and an LSTM model across different hierarchical levels in a sales forecast setting (similar to the M5 forecasting competition scenario). Before I elaborate further on my setting I want to be upfront with my question:

**How can I use the same validation technique (preferably something like k=5 kfold validation using sci-kit learn time series split) across all models (TS, ML and DL) to make the same comparison using Python?**

My forecasting horizon is 10 days. In the end, I want to have a cross-validation score and a test score for the last 10 days. I test different hypotheses using different external data as well as clustering methods. However, I find it very confusing to align the validation technique across all models to make them perfectly comparable and replicable.

I use autoARIMA to tune the ARIMA model. As far as I understood it minimises AIC and BIC. I use sci-kit learn's time series split (k=5) to tune lightGBM minimising MAE and finally I use a similar handwritten technique for LSTM with a 30-day look-back period and 10 days forecasts minimising MAE as well.

How would you approach such a problem?  How would you structure the code and scripts? Is there a library out there that I can use for all models or do I have to split the data manually and compare models using a for loop?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

While your question reads more like a programming question (since you use Python, scikit-learn is the obvious eco-system to use, which has lots of support for defining cross-validation etc. including [things for splitting time series](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html)), but has a statistics component so I'll answer that.

Simple cross-validation is usually inappropriate for time series, if your task is to predict the future from the past. In such a case you want a past-vs-future split. You can (and probably should to stabilize the validation score) still use several such splits. Here's a good discussion of [validation sets](https://www.fast.ai/posts/2017-11-13-validation-sets.html) (esp. [this bit](https://www.fast.ai/posts/2017-11-13-validation-sets.html#time-series)) and Kaggle competitions with time series data will usually have a lot of good code/example/discussions of how to do validaiton there.

Comment: Thank you, you may be right, it may be a more programming question. However, my question regarding statistics is more about the following point. Do I have to use the same validation technique for all models and how is this done when comparing for example ARIMA and LSTM. As far as I understood, the models do get trained very differently. Thus I ask, how to set up a validation to get the most appropriate measurements. Do you know what I mean? Sorry if my wording is confusing. It is because I am confused myself :D.

Comment: Yes, I would set up the validation exactly the same.  Otherwise, things are not comparable. There's no real problem in doing that for ARIMA and LSTM.

Comment: Use a holdout sample. If you have $T$ data points, then fit your models to the first $T-h$ data points and forecast out into the last $h$ points. Then assess each model's accuracy on these $h$ data points. Alternatively, roll this evaluation forward multiple times ("rolling origins"). [See here.](https://otexts.com/fpp3/accuracy.html) For error measures and pitfalls in selecting them, [see here](https://forecasting-encyclopedia.com/theory.html#point_forecast_accuracy_measures).